# Blank Page on production using Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix, inertiajs

I built a single page application (SPA) using Laravel 8 + Vue.js + InertiaJs. Everything is working fine in the development environment, but when I compile assets for production, it shows me a blank page, and there is no error in the console. All assets are loading correctly with a 200 code, and everything seems to be OK, but the Vue app is not mounting!

**webpack.mix.js**

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-workbox');

mix.webpackConfig({
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js',
    }
}).js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract(['vue'])
    .version();
```

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2ftD.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijd1t.png)

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4JXO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the inertiajs `webpack.mix.js` provided by the [pingCRM github](https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm/blob/a3758546dcd6a2f897c660aed18ef8eb240e7114/webpack.mix.js):

```
const path = require('path')
const mix = require('laravel-mix')
const cssImport = require('postcss-import')
const cssNesting = require('postcss-nesting')

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix
  .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .vue()
  .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    // prettier-ignore
    cssImport(),
    cssNesting(),
    require('tailwindcss'),
  ])
  .webpackConfig({
    output: { chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js?id=[chunkhash]' },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js',
        '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
      },
    },
  })
  .version()
  .sourceMaps()
```

note you may have to follow the instructions for setting up `tailwindcss` which can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#tailwindcss), only do this if you plan to use it otherwise remove the `require('tailwindcss'),` from the webpack file

you also may need to `npm install --save-dev postcss-import` and `npm install --save-dev postcss-nesting` the `--save-dev` flag will add it to your `package.json` file for future reference